# Get current int day of week is increased by one

Tags: java, android, date, calendar

i have to get the current day of week as int and i'm using `Calendar` but i'm getting it increased by one, why?

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTime(new Date());
int dayOfWeek = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

It returns 3 for today that is Tuesday, and not 2.

Comment: Is counting from zero ?

Comment: In this case, it is increased by two so

Comment: So Sunday is equal to 1?

Comment: Not only it counts from 1, but your week starts on Sunday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Values go like this:

```
Sunday = 1
Monday = 2
Tuesday = 3
Wednesday = 4
Thursday = 5
Friday = 6
Saturday = 7
```

You can check it like this:

```
System.out.println(Calendar.SUNDAY);
```

Comment: @Fondesa [See here to save some time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)

Answer (score 2):

The values are defined in the `java.util.Calendar` class:

```
/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Sunday.
 */
public final static int SUNDAY = 1;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Monday.
 */
public final static int MONDAY = 2;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Tuesday.
 */
public final static int TUESDAY = 3;
```